# boost coroutine how to retrieve function return value aftercoro_t is finished

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine

I am calling non-void functions using boost::coroutine like

```
typedef boost::coroutines::coroutine< int(void) > coro_t;
typedef coro_t::caller_type Yield_target;

myClass* do_something(Yield_target& yield)
{
    myClass* m = new myClass;
    // ... do smt
    yield();
    // ... do smt
    return m;
}
```

And then I call my function with binding it to boost coroutine. After the function (coroutine) finishes how can I get the return value of myClass*?

Answer (score 0):

The type **coro_t::caller_type** you mentioned in your question statement may be deprecated, due to it not being featured in [more recent Boost Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/coroutine2/doc/html/index.html). However, [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/coroutine2/doc/html/coroutine2/coroutine/asymmetric.html) in that more recent documentation you may see a phrase in **coroutine<>::push_type** section that *"you can not retrieve values from another execution context with this kind of coroutine"*.

Though I am not certain on how you intend to use couroutine library, I suspect you will use **coroutine<>::push_type** more frequently than **coroutine<>::pull_type**, so I guess you will need to find another way to retrieve the return value, rather than the library itself.